# Map UnicodeString as key to Class as value C++Builder

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, c++builder, stdmap

I'm using C++Builder XE7. I want to use map with a UnicodeString as key and a class as value.

This is my class: Historique.h

```
#ifndef HistoriqueH
#define HistoriqueH
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <string>    

class MyHistorique
{
    public:
        __fastcall MyHistorique();
        __fastcall MyHistorique(const MyHistorique& mh);

        //Getters
        String __fastcall getNumClient(){return numClient;}
        bool __fastcall getTypeAppel(){return typeAppel;}
        String __fastcall getCodeClient(){return codeClient;}
        String __fastcall getDate(){return date;}
        String __fastcall getHeure(){return heure;}
        String __fastcall getNumCti(){return numCti;}
        bool __fastcall getAppelRecuManque(){return appelRecuManque;}
        String __fastcall getDebutConvers(){return debutConvers;}
        String __fastcall getFinConvers(){return finConvers;}
        String __fastcall getDureeConvers(){return dureeConvers;}
        bool __fastcall getFlag(){return flag;}

        //Setters
        void __fastcall setNumClient(String nc){numClient = nc;}
        void __fastcall setTypeAppel(bool ta){typeAppel = ta;}
        void __fastcall setCodeClient(String cc){codeClient = cc;}
        void __fastcall setDate(String d){date = d;}
        void __fastcall setHeure(String h){heure = h;}
        void __fastcall setNumCti(String nCti){numCti = nCti;}
        void __fastcall setAppelRecuManque(bool arm){appelRecuManque = arm;}
        void __fastcall setDebutConvers(String dc){debutConvers = dc;}
        void __fastcall setFinConvers(String fc){finConvers = fc;}
        void __fastcall setDureeConvers(String dureeC){dureeConvers = dureeC;}
        void __fastcall setFlag(bool f){flag = f;}

    private:
        String numClient;
        bool typeAppel;
        String codeClient;
        String date;
        String heure;
        String numCti;
        bool appelRecuManque;
        String debutConvers;
        String finConvers;
        String dureeConvers;
        bool flag;
};
```

And in my Application.h:

```
#include <map>
#include "Historique.h"

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    public:
    std::map<UnicodeString, MyHistorique> myMap;
};
```

And in my Application.cpp:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::XPhonePc1EvtIdCall(TObject *Sender, long nIdCall)
{
    ShowMessage(nIdCall);
    myMap[nIdCall] = new MyHistorique();  
}
```

What I want is to create an empty object and assign it with the `nIdCall` but I have this error:

> [bcc32 Erreur] ApplicationPhonePC.cpp(496): E2285 Impossible de trouver une correspondance pour 'operator MyHistorique::=(MyHistorique *)'
>     Contexte d'analyseur complet
>       ApplicationPhonePC.cpp(493): analyse : void _fastcall TForm1::XPhonePc1EvtIdCall(TObject *,long)

Comment: Why do you want to use `UnicodeString` as a key when you clearly are working with `long` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the compiler cannot find an `operator=` defined that can assign a `MyHistorique*` pointer to a `MyHistorique` object instance.  And rightly so, because you did not define one (nor should you).

Your `std::map` contains actual `MyHistorique` object instances, not pointers to objects, so you need to remove the call to `new` so the compiler can invoke `MyHistorique`'s copy assignment operator instead:

```
MyHistorique tmp;
myMap[nIdCall] = tmp;
```

Or simply:

```
myMap[nIdCall] = MyHistorique();
```

Alternatively, I would suggest adding a method to `MyHistorique` to reset its current fields to default values:

```
class MyHistorique
{
public:
    void Reset();
};

void MyHistorique::Reset()
{
    numClient = ...;
    typeAppel = ...;
    codeClient = ...;
    ... and so on ...
}
```

And then call that method like this:

```
myMap[nIdCall].Reset();
```

Note, however, that this would be redundant if `nIdCall` does not exist in the `std::map` yet.  When `nIdCall` is newly inserted, its associated object will be default-constructed before returned by `std::map::operator[]`, so you would not need to call `Reset()`.  You can use `std::map::find()` to get around that redundant operation:

```
std::map<UnicodeString, MyHistorique>::iterator iter = myMap.find(nIdCall);
if (iter != myMap.end())
    iter->second.Reset();
else
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(nIdCall, MyHistorique()));
```

On the other hand, if you know that `nIdCall` will always be a new value and never pre-exist in the `std::map`, you could just ignore everything above and do this instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::XPhonePc1EvtIdCall(TObject *Sender, long nIdCall)
{
    ShowMessage(nIdCall);
    myMap[nIdCall];  
}
```

Comment: is correct. I just wanted to add that you could use boost's [ptr_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html) which can accept pointers and does the cleanup automatically.

Comment: Oh I better understand and it works. I've been on it for few days. Thanks a lot Remy. And thanks everyone. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Try myMap[nIdCall] = new MyHistorique();

Don't forget to delete your instances from your map when your'e done

Comment: Oups sorry, I forgot to change that. This is the actual errors now.
[ilink32 Erreur] Error: '__fastcall MyHistorique::MyHistorique()' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\SRAADM\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\APPLICATIONPHONEPC.OBJ
[ilink32 Erreur] Error: '__fastcall MyHistorique::MyHistorique(MyHistorique&)' externe non résolu, référencé depuis C:\USERS\SRAADM\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\PROJETS\WIN32\DEBUG\APPLICATIONPHONEPC.OBJ
[ilink32 Erreur] Error: Impossible d'effectuer le lien

Comment: Okay thanks. I've try this and i have this one:

[bcc32 Erreur] ApplicationPhonePC.cpp(496): E2285 Impossible de trouver une correspondance pour 'operator MyHistorique::=(MyHistorique *)'
  Contexte d'analyseur complet
    ApplicationPhonePC.cpp(493): analyse : void _fastcall TForm1::XPhonePc1EvtIdCall(TObject *,long)

Comment: Not knowing French...but change your map to store pointers of type MyHistorique i.e. std::map<UnicodeString, MyHistorique* >

Comment: Please DON'T change the map to store pointers!  That just puts more burden on the programmer to manage the memory allocations manually.  At least if you are using C++11 (the Win64 or mobile compilers), you can use `std::unique_ptr<MyHistorique>` instead of `MyHistorique*` in the `map`.  But that is not an option in earlier C++ versions (the Win32 compiler).  It is also unnecessary in this situation.  See my answer for a different solution.